# Installing OpenCV in Tinker Board

Tags: opencv, debian

I have downloaded `20170817-tinker-board-linaro-stretch-alip-v2.0.1.img` for Tinker Board.  I am trying to install OpenCV 3.0.0.  I have followed the instructions given here : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/.

I was not able to install libjasper-dev. Hence, instead of libpng12-dev, I have installed libpng.

I am trying to compile OpenCV on Tinker Board since yesterday morning. But have been getting following errors during building process:

`/usr/include/c++/6/cmath:106:11: error: ::acos has not been declared`

Followed by all the math formula triggers similar errors.

Which Debian version is stable for OpenCV?  Should I install a lower version of OpenCV? Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully managed to install OpenCV on a TinkerBoard.  The following were the steps:

1. Format a 16 GB memory card to FAT32
2. Download debian image `20170817-tinker-board-linaro-stretch-alip-v2.0.1.img` for tinker board from [here](https://www.asus.com/in/Single-Board-Computer/Tinker-Board/HelpDesk_Download/).
3. Copy the img file on to the memory card

`sudo dd if=/path/to/your/imgfile of=/path/to/your/memorycard bs=4M`

a lot of help on this is already available in SO.

4. Before powering on ensure that you connect your tinker board to the internet through a lan cable.
5. Once powered on reset the system time with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.  Debian image for tinker board already has ntp installed.  Wait a couple of minutes for the tinker board to adjust the board time from the network.
6. To install opencv and its dependant library, I have taken the instructions given [here](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh) ....though I had to make some custom library installations but it was very helpful.  Please note, my purpose of using Opencv on Tinker Board is to process live video's and hence my focus was more towards installing appropriate video codecs.

The following were the steps:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

You may face the following warning messages during installation of perl applications:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.

perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.utf8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Though this doesn't impact your installation of OpenCV, after spending 3 days in trying to compile Opencv on tinker board I do not want to leave anything for a chance.

Use the following to suppress these warning messages:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Thanks to this [post](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_in_Debian).

```
# INSTALL THE DEPENDENCIES

# Build tools:
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake

# GUI (if you want to use GTK instead of Qt, replace 'qt5-default' with 'libgtkglext1-dev' and remove '-DWITH_QT=ON' option in CMake):  I just went with qt5 itself.

sudo apt-get install -y qt5-default libvtk6-dev

# Media I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libopenexr-dev libgdal-dev
```

Pls note libjasper-dev is unavailable for this version of Debian and hence I have removed from the above Media I/O list.

```
# Video I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libv4l-dev libxine2-dev

sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-*
sudo apt-get install libxine-dev

# Parallelism and linear algebra libraries:
sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev

# Python:
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-tk python-numpy python3-dev python3-tk python3-numpy

sudo apt-get install python-pip

# Java:
sudo apt-get install -y ant default-jdk

# Documentation:
sudo apt-get install -y doxygen
```

Get OpenCV.  I decided to go with version 3.0.0 as my development was in this version.  You may choose a different version.

```
sudo apt-get install -y unzip wget
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.0.0.zip
unzip 3.0.0.zip
rm 3.0.0.zip
```

Build OpenCV.

```
mv opencv-3.0.0 OpenCV
cd OpenCV
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_FFMPEG=0 -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF ..
```

A change here from the original script - is the addition of `-DWITH_FFMPEG=0`, as FFMPEG library was missing and I was not in a frame of mind to install the same.  You may want to do so.

```
make
```

Though TinkerBoard supports `make -j4` i chose to go slow with `make`.  The compile with `make` took almost 2.5 hours with lot of seemingly indentation errors in c++ codes but finally the compile gets over.

```
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig

$ python
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.0.0'
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install libxine2-dev

Answer (score 2):

After few days finally I got good setup. My post improves the previous answer.

Steps is similar like it was before me, but I changed few strings, because I had different errors.

In my case for new Asus Tinker Board I installed:

1. 20170928-tinker-board-linaro-stretch-alip-v2.0.3
2. opencv-3.3.0 with opencv_contrib-3.3.0.

First start of tinker board.

```
sudo apt-get -y update 
sudo apt-get -y upgrade 
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

It necessary to remove default (old) OpenCV:

```
sudo apt-get remove libopencv*
sudo apt-get -y autoremove

# INSTALL THE DEPENDENCIES

# Build tools:
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake

# GUI (I had errors with Qt, so I did next)
sudo apt-get install -y libgtkglext1-dev libvtk6-dev

# Media I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libopenexr-dev libgdal-dev

# Video I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libv4l-dev libxine2-dev libxine-dev

sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-*

# Parallelism and linear algebra libraries:
sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev

# Python:
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-tk python-numpy python3-dev python3-tk python3-numpy

sudo apt-get install python-pip

# Java:
sudo apt-get install -y ant default-jdk

# Documentation:
sudo apt-get install -y doxygen
```

Get OpenCV.

```
cd ~
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.3.0.zip 
unzip opencv.zip
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.3.0.zip
unzip opencv_contrib.zip
```

Compile and Install OpenCV

```
cd ~/opencv-3.3.0/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_FFMPEG=0 -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF ..
```

CMake should start to build your configuration, after a couple of minutes you should see:

```
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done       
 -- Build files have been written to: ./opencv-3.3.0/build
```

If you can't see Generating done then some issues have been occurred. Read error messages and the error log file to investigate.

I did without examples, but you can try. Qt I deleted.

```
make
```

Better without -j4.

```
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Test the installation

```
linaro@tinkerboard:~$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

installing ffmpeg ( the previous answers skiped this ) 
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg libav-tools x264 x265

I also recommend installing the additional packages and enabling neon and vfpv3 when compiling the opncv files. This should give significant improvement in performance: 
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/09/optimizing-opencv-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question late. I am adding this answer for the future reference of the people. Here is the official documentation of Tinkerboard.

https://tinkerboarding.co.uk/wiki/index.php/CSI-camera

I just changed the version to the latest version at this time (3.4.1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
#Install a few developer tools
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git cmake pkg-config
#Install image I/O packages which allow us to load image file formats such as JPEG, PNG, TIFF, etc.
sudo apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libpng-dev
#Install video I/O packages
sudo apt-get install -y libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
#Install the GTK development library
sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev
#Various operations inside of OpenCV (such as matrix operations) can be optimized using added dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev gfortran
#Install the Python 2.7 and Python 3 header files 
sudo apt-get install -y python2.7-dev python3-dev python-opencv
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.zip
unzip 3.4.1.zip
cd opencv-3.4.1
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
sudo make install
```

It took around 90 minutes to compile.